# Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions with $f_n $ bounded. If $\{f_n\}$ converge point-wise to $f$ then $f$ is bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions with $f_n $ bounded. If $\{f_n\}$ converge point-wise to $f$ then $f$ is bounded ?

I've already proved that $f$ is bounded if $f_n$ is bounded and $\{f_n\}$ converge uniformly to $f$ (using proof by contradiction).

However, I cannot seem to find a counter example that this property doesn't hold when uniform convergence is substituted with point-wise convergence.

Comment: Do you plan to delete the present post after it gets some answers, as you deleted [this other post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/768620/6179) with neither warning nor explanation?

Answer (score 2):

You need a uniform bound (independent of $n$). Otherwise, e.g, $$ f_n(x):=\min(n,\exp(x)) $$
converges pointwise to $\exp(x)$ but the limit is not bounded.

Comment: so let's say we have a sequence of functions $f_{n}$ that we know converges pointwise to something that's bounded. Does that necessarily imply that $\{f_{n}\}$ is uniformly bounded?

Comment: @JessyCat No, of course not. Consider a sequence of continuous piecewise linear maps $f_n$ such that  $f_n(x)=0$ outside of $[n, n+1]$, which is linear on $[n, n+1/2]$ such that $f(n+1/2)= n$ and linear again on $(n+1/2, n+1]$ ( a sequence of spikes of width $1$ and of increasing height). This converges pointwise to the zero function, but is not bounded. You can find similar examples on bounded intervals, as well (just make the spike narrow with width tending to $0$).

Answer (score 2):

Take 
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac 1x \text{ for $1/n < x < 1$}\\
n \text{ for $0<x<1/n$}
\end{cases}.$$